# Problem with nstalling Steam on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver

Tags: 18.04, steam

I can't install steam on ubuntu 18.04, i have many problems, when i put: sudo apt-get install steam appears this problem.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

AFTER

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

So... when i try to install these packages there are troubles too.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libllvm6.0:i386 (>= 1:6.0~svn298832-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libgl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Press return to continue:
```

Finally. What can i do? I need to resolve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Is this a clean ubuntu install? Are you using some PPA with conflicting packages?

Comment: It's clean. I installed latest ubuntu's version for developer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't customized your Ubuntu installation, you should install Steam by downloading a .deb package provided by Valve [here.](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb)

Select *Open File*. Ubuntu Software will launch. Click on *Install*, enter your password if you are prompted to, and you're done here. Steam should be installed.